# Как создать базу данных средствами mysqli либо PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Как можно подключиться к серверу mysql и выполнить команду **Create database**?

Как-то так, только без указания базы (4-параметра):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

После чего выполнить, например, команду **mysql_create_db**.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: дак не переавайте имя бд, в чем проблема то?

Comment: с тремя параметрами, разве работать будет? Как затем выполнить тогда команду создания базы в mysqli, либо PDO?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2583707/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прежде всего Вы подключаетесь к серверу, [4 параметр(имя бд) не обязателен при подключении и позволяет использовать бд для запросов по умолчанию](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.construct.php).

Примеры создания базы данных для различных подходов ниже.

**Mysqli объектно ориентированный стиль**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

**Mysqli процедурный стиль**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Create database
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE myDB";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Database created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

**PDO**

```
$root="root"; 
$root_password="root_password"; 

$user='newuser';
$pass='newpass';
$db="newdb"; 

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $root, $root_password);

    $dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `$db`;
            CREATE USER '$user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$pass';
            GRANT ALL ON `$db`.* TO '$user'@'localhost';
            FLUSH PRIVILEGES;") 
    or die(print_r($db->errorInfo(), true));

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("DB ERROR: ". $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, я что-то протупил тут)).